# C++ read CSV table in columnar store with different datatypes

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, import-from-csv

I want to read a CSV file in which a database table is contained (TPCH). Each file has different numbers of columns, rows and datatypes.

For example:

```
 file1: Int, double, char[]
 file2: double, char[], int, int
```

One further requirement is the each column should reside in an array (for each column an array - not per row).

***My Solution:*** Currently I am creating arrays on runtime with new depending on the data type and the size of the csv file

```
 e.g. file1: would be int[] , double[]...
```

Then I am storing the start address of my array as an void* in an map(int,void*).

When I want to read values from the array I have to retrieve the void* and cast it according to the type.

As you can see I have a lot of pointers and casting which is naughty. Is there a better approach of storing a Table in Columnar format? I wanted to use arrays because I often copy them and transfer them over the network. Also, I don't want to use the boost library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pointers are often leading to montains of headaches. First, I suggest you to use the STL containers, such as `std::vector`, it will make your life easier. No need of boost, not even a new C++ compiler because `std::vector` is here from a long time.

But I don't understand why you want to store the start address of your array. Anyway, if you just want to store an address, you can use the header file `<cstdint>` and use types `intptr_t / uintptr_t`, guaranted to be able to hold a `void*`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The point with vector is that I need a map in which I am able to store the vectors, but they have different types like vector(int) or vector(double). Is it possible to store these different vector types in one single map?
If I got it wrong just correct me, but I need to store the start address because my array is dynamically allocated and resides in the heap.

Comment: There are `boost::any` or `boost::variant`, but if you cannot use them, we need to think of another approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for `variant`. In C++17 we will have this as part of the standard library, but for now we are stuck using the `boost` implementation.

If you don't want to use `boost` there are several options for you, but they're all at least a little bit gross.

1. `void*`. This is not desirable for numerous reasons. You know that already so I won't delve into it here.
2. `union`. This is also not desirable when dealing with objects that have constructors and destructors. You have to remember to call the destructors and you have to know to call the constructors in place. Better than `void*`, but only just barely. Assuming you are dealing with all primitive types, `std::vector<some_union_type>` might not be so bad, but once you bring in dynamically sized strings you're in a world of hurt.
3. Byte manipulation. Store everything in `char[]` (more specifically, `std::vector<char>`) and keep metadata about the datatype in some kind of enum. Use that enum to cast the bytes to the correct type. This is a pretty hairy solution to put together by hand, but it is similar to how `variant` is typically implemented.
4. Runtime polymorphism. Create a parent class, then a child class for each datatype. Dynamically allocate the child classes (storing them in a `std::unique_ptr`) and get them out by doing `dynamic_cast` until you get the right type (or store the datatype in an enum and cast based on that). This is probably the most "high-level" solution, and is probably easier to get right than the first three solutions.
5. Concept-based polymorphism. This is basically hand-rolling a special case of `any` (mentioned in another answer). Sean Parent covers it [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil). For your case you might find yourself implementing something like a `variant::visitor` pattern to get at the data you want.

Perhaps using `boost::variant` does not look so bad after all. ;)